# How to find number is between some specified range in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, range

I want to find the number which is input for the Python function. The input value is not fixed; it may be in thousands, lacks or cores.

I'm using Python 2.7.

Example:

```
def check(number):

   if(10000 <= number <= 50000):
      print "Number is between 10000 & 50000"

   if(50001 <= number <= 100000):
      print "Number is between 50001 & 100000"

   if(100000 <= number <= 500000):
      print "Number is between 100000 & 500000"

if __name__ == "__main__":

   with open("input.csv", "r+b") as f:
      m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
      reader = csv.DictReader(iter(m.readline, ""))
      for read in reader:
         num = read['time']
         check(num)#calling check function
```

**input.csv -**

```
 time
 404907
 404863
 404345
 403630
 403562
 120279146
 120279128
 216870
 58460
```

I'm reading input.csv file. and I want to check if the `time` column is in a specific range, but it is not working properly.

What am I missing?

Comment: what is not working properly about it? (I see some indent issues and "//" is not a valid comment in python)

Comment: What are "lacks" or "cores" in this context?

Comment: @user2357112- It is time in microseconds...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check `int(num)` instead of just `num`, because you need to compare `integer vs integer`
Also seems there is a typo error in your third condition

```
   if(100000 <= number <= 500000):
      print "Number is between 100000 & 500000
```

I supposed you should have the following line:

```
   if(100001 <= number <= 500000):
      print "Number is between 100001 & 500000"`
```

Comment: @Arseniy- Thank you...It's working now...Problem is -  **int(num)**

Answer (score 1):

Your `num` is a string, and you're comparing it with integers.  In Python 2 it is legal to compare a string with an integer, but the result will not be useful (in Python 3 it is an error) .

You need to call `check(int(num))` for the comparisons to work as intended.